# Why method isn't allowed?

Tags: asp.net, razor, blazor, httpwebrequest, .net-5

I prepared a razor component for my contact form. The SubmitForm method looks like:

```
private async Task<string> SubmitForm()
{
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ContactFormModel);
    var stringContent = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await Http.PostAsync("/Contact/SendMessage", stringContent);        
    Logger.LogInformation("Executed PostAsync.");
    Debug.Write("Executed PostAsync");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var resultContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return resultContent;
    }
    else
        return "failed";
}
```

In line 5 it should send a post request to "/Contact/SendMessage".

```
The ContactController looks like:

    namespace MannsBlog.Controllers.Web
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ContactController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMailService _mailService;
        private readonly ILogger<ContactController> _logger;
        private readonly GoogleCaptchaService _captcha;
        public ContactController(IMailService mailService,
            ILogger<ContactController> logger,
            GoogleCaptchaService captcha)
        {
            _mailService = mailService;
            _logger = logger;
            _captcha = captcha;
        }

        [HttpGet("")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SendMessage([FromBody] ContactFormModel form)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var spamState = VerifyNoSpam(form);
                    if (!spamState.Success)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError("Spamstate wasn't succeeded");
                        return BadRequest(new { Reason = spamState.Reason });
                    }

                    if (!_captcha.Verify(form.Recaptcha))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("The submission failed the spam bot verification.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _mailService.SendMail("ContactTemplate.txt", form.Name, form.Email, form.Subject, form.Message);
                    }
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Your message was successfully sent." });
                }
                _logger.LogError("Modelstate wasnt valid");
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "ModelState wasnt valid..." });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Failed to send email from contact page", ex.Message);
                return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message });
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

But if i'm execute it, i get in response the RequestMessage "

> RequestMessage    {Method: POST, RequestUri:
> 'https://saschamanns.de/Contact/SendMessage', Version: 1.1, Content:
> System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers: {   Request-Context:
> appId=cid-v1:64d2a34b-4aea-4d0b-8163-a49082988533   Request-Id:
> |fec381c24e685e4b8eddd2b24064a1e4.a6d3a3ff85fe5c44.   traceparent:
> 00-fec381c24e685e4b8eddd2b24064a1e4-a6d3a3ff85fe5c44-00
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8   Content-Length: 572
> }}    System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage"

and as ReasonPhrase "Method not allowed".

But why? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL is flawed.  Two options:

1. `Use Http.PostAsync("/Contact", stringContent); //no /SendMessage`

or

2. In the controller, use `[HttpPost("SendMessage")]`

and, some unrelated suggestions from codereview :

- don't use `.Result`:

```
//var resultContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  var resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

- consider `System.Text.Json` instead of Newtonsoft.
- when you use `Http.PostAsJsonAsync(...)` you resolve both issues in one go.